# Liferay 6.1 Absolute Path

Tags: java, liferay-6

Does anybody know how to find the Liferay absolute path in Java? I need to store there some data, and my app might run on different OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using `portletConext().getAbsolutePath` or `getRealPath` for real path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the liferay constant for this property :

```
PropsKey.LIFERAY_HOME
```

so

```
PropsUtil.get(PropsKey.LIFERAY_HOME);
```